# PHP looping over multidimensional array with key

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array with different arrays in them with values. I want to loop over these arrays inside to get all the values but for some reason It only goes over the first array.

Here's what the array looks like:
This array's name is slots.

```
Array
(
    [41] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attractie] => attractie1
                    [start] => 0930
                    [end] => 1200
                    [personen] => 
                    [catering] => 1
                    [bedrijfsnaam] => attractie1
                    [link] => http:
                    [color] => dd0330
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attractie] => attractie1
                    [start] => 1000
                    [end] => 1230
                    [personen] => 
                    [catering] => 1
                    [bedrijfsnaam] => Bedrijf2
                    [link] => http:
                    [color] => e49fca
                )
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [attractie] => attractie2
                    [start] => 0930
                    [end] => 1030
                    [personen] => 
                    [catering] => 1
                    [bedrijfsnaam] => Bedrijf4
                    [link] => http:
                    [color] => f7e300
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attractie] => attractie2
                    [start] => 0930
                    [end] => 1030
                    [personen] => 
                    [catering] => 0
                    [bedrijfsnaam] => bedrijf5
                    [link] => http:
                    [color] => f78f1e
                )

        )

)
```

So this is what my loop looks like:

```
$i=0;
foreach($slots[$attractieIDs[$i]] as $s){

        $myOrders[] = array( 'attractie' => $s['attractie'],
                             'name' => $s['bedrijfsnaam'],
                             'start' => $s['start'],
                             'end' => $s['end'],
                             'link' => $s['link'], 
                             'personen' => $s['personen'],
                             'catering' => $s['catering'],
                             'color' => $s['color'],
                           ); 
         $i++;
}
```

`attractieID` is an array with the id's in them the (41 and 52).

When I print out `$myOrders` I only get to see the values of the array with id 41 it doesn't go to the next array with a new id.

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I would like to output the values of the array with id 52 as well

Comment: But how it should look **exactly**

Comment: Just all the values(name, attractie, etc.) of every item in all the arrays in my big $slots array

Comment: Man why don't you put desired array structure in your question.?

Comment: @Anant Okay I am sorry I will do it now

Comment: I think disired array will looks like your $slot array, as you give description ?

Comment: @Frank Lucas If you need values of every item, that what my given loop do.

Comment: @FrankLucas the answer you selected will not work in the case if your original array have more indexes apart from  `41, 52`.

Comment: @Anant I am aware of this, My $attractieIDs array is build in an other loop independant from this one so it's fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will merge entries from 41 and 52 into one array and you will not be able to tell which one was which.

```
$sourceArray = .... your source array here :)
$attractieIDs = array(41, 52);

foreach($attractieIDs as $id) {
   foreach($sourceArray[$id] as $attr) {
     $myOrders[] = $attr;
   }
}
```

Comment: I get an `Illegal offset type` and Invalid argument `supplied for foreach()` error

Comment: Forgot one level. Try now.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, I retract my previous comment, however there is something wrong: you should only need 2 loops. Now you will only get values, no keys, since $s is not an array.

Comment: This seems wrong (unless the OP has been very unclear in expressing), because this does not give you the keys "attractie", "bedrijfsnaam", "start".... Only their values are returned in one big array. I put your code [here](https://eval.in/556736).

Comment: Also don't it will  restrict because of `$attractieIDs = array(41, 52);`? what happen if lot of other indexes will come? how much indexes will be hardcoded?

Comment: @trincot indeed, nested too much. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @Anant this was OP requirement: `attractieIDs is an array with the id's in them the (41 and 52).`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
foreach ($attractieIDs as $id) {
    foreach ($slots[$id] as $s) {
        $myOrders[] = $s;
    }
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/556733)

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop:

```
foreach($slots as $outer_arr){

    foreach($outer_arr as $s) {
        $myOrders[] = array( 'attractie' => $s['attractie'],
              'name' => $s['bedrijfsnaam'],
              'start' => $s['start'],
              'end' => $s['end'],
              'link' => $s['link'], 
              'personen' => $s['personen'],
              'catering' => $s['catering'],
              'color' => $s['color'],
        ); 

    }


}
```

But still not clear with your desired output.

Comment: What should $outer_arr be?

Comment: The $outer_arr will contain the array with index `41` and `52` and one more foreach loop for iterate over the array.

Comment: If you can add `array variable` NOT `array output` I can test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This loop will output any value inside your array regardless on what index you have.

```
<?php
$test = array(
    '41' => array( 
        array('attractie' => 'attractie1',
             'start' => '0930',
             'end' => '1200',
             'personen' => NULL,
             'catering' => '1',
             'bedrijfsnaam' => 'attractie1',
             'link' => 'http:',
             'color' =>'dd0330'),
        array('attractie' => 'attractie1',
             'start' => '1000',
             'end' => '1230',
             'personen' => NULL,
             'catering' => '1',
             'bedrijfsnaam' => 'Bedrijf2',
             'link' => 'http:',
             'color' =>'e49fca'),
            ),
    '51' => array( 
        array('attractie' => 'attractie2',
             'start' => '0930',
             'end' => '1030',
             'personen' => NULL,
             'catering' => '1',
             'bedrijfsnaam' => 'Bedrijf4',
             'link' => 'http:',
             'color' =>'f7e300'),
        array('attractie' => 'attractie2',
             'start' => '0930',
             'end' => '1030',
             'personen' => NULL,
             'catering' => '0',
             'bedrijfsnaam' => 'bedrijf5',
             'link' => 'http:',
             'color' =>'f78f1e'),
            )
    );

foreach ($test as $a => $val) {
    echo "<b>Index $a</b><br><br>";
    foreach ($val as $b) {
        foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
            echo "<b>$key</b> - $value<br>";
        }
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Index 41

attractie - attractie1
start - 0930
end - 1200
personen - 
catering - 1
bedrijfsnaam - attractie1
link - http:
color - dd0330
attractie - attractie1
start - 1000
end - 1230
personen - 
catering - 1
bedrijfsnaam - Bedrijf2
link - http:
color - e49fca


Index 51

attractie - attractie2
start - 0930
end - 1030
personen - 
catering - 1
bedrijfsnaam - Bedrijf4
link - http:
color - f7e300
attractie - attractie2
start - 0930
end - 1030
personen - 
catering - 0
bedrijfsnaam - bedrijf5
link - http:
color - f78f1e
```